# Custom Pipe causes the ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when running a unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, angular-pipe

In my template I have this:

```
...
<tbody>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
    <tr *ngIf="item.isBoolean">
      <td><a href="#">{{item.description}}</a></td>
      <td>{{item | customPipe}}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</tbody>
...
```

And this is my unit test:

```
it('should behave...', () => {
  const trs: DebugElement[] = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('tbody tr'));

  expect(trs.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
});
```

When I execute the test, I get the following:

```
Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'value'. Current value: 'undefined'.. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0100
error properties: Object({ code: '100' })
Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'value'. Current value: 'undefined'.. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0100
    at throwErrorIfNoChangesMode (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:6723:1)
    at bindingUpdated (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:12854:1
```

That `value` is what the `customPipe` returns.

Comment: Does it happen on `npm start` as well?

Comment: @AliF50, do you mean serving the app? No it doesn`t, it just happen when I run the tests

Comment: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/ I find that article the best for debugging the issue.

Comment: Sorry @AliF50, but that article say nothing about the error happening in tests when using the pipe

Comment: Right but I am thinking `item` changes for the pipe to run again so the issue can be why is the value of `item` changing in between the two change detections that happen in dev mode.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue today during testing my Angular app through `Jasmine`. Please check the code snippet below which solved my problem (courtesy: https://www.codegrepper.com).

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, AfterContentChecked } from '@angular/core';
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef){}

  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    this.ref.detectChanges();
  }
```